# Manejo de sesiones en PHP para Login

Tags: php, session

Tengo una aplicacion en php con login funcional y unos cruds, pero el problema que tengo es que en el front controller quiero colocar una condicional con una variable de sesion para que detecte si esta autenticado puedo acceder a los cruds, si no que lo redirija al login de nuevo.

Codigo de frontcontroller index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'model/database.php';

$controller = 'Administrador';
session_start();


// Este if es el que no me funciona
if (!is_null($_SESSION['session_ini'])) {
    if(!isset($_REQUEST['c']))
    {
        require_once "controller/$controller.controller.php";
        $controller = ucwords($controller) . 'Controller';
        $controller = new $controller;
        $controller->Index();    
    }
    else
    {
        // Obtenemos el controlador que queremos cargar
        $controller = strtolower($_REQUEST['c']);
        $accion = isset($_REQUEST['a']) ? $_REQUEST['a'] : 'Index';

        // Instanciamos el controlador
        require_once "controller/$controller.controller.php";
        $controller = ucwords($controller) . 'Controller';
        $controller = new $controller;

        // Llama la accion
        call_user_func( array( $controller, $accion ) );
    }
} else {
    require_once "controller/login.controller.php";
    $controller = ucwords('login') . 'Controller';
    $controller = new $controller;
    $controller->Index();    
}
```

Login.Cotroller.php en el metodo de auth donde autentico al usuario y doy los datos a las variables de session:

```
public function auth(){
        session_start();
        $log = new Login();

        if(!is_null($_REQUEST['correo'])){
            $log = $this->model->Obtener($_REQUEST['correo']);
            $pass = md5($_REQUEST['contrasena']);

            if ($_REQUEST['correo'] == $log->correo && $pass == $log->contrasena) {

                $_SESSION['session_ini'] = true;
                $_SESSION['nombres'] = $log->nombres;
                $_SESSION['apellidos'] = $log->apellidos;
                $_SESSION['correo'] = $log->correo;
                header('Location: index.php?c=Administrador');
            } else {
                header('Location: index.php?c=Login');
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Deduzco (corrígame si me equivoco) que lo que pretende hacer es que si la variable de sesión del usuario existe se le redirija al proceso de login, y que si no realice otra función. Si es este el funcionamiento que plantea, debería quitarle el ! al primer `if`, es decir, que en vez de `if (!is_null($_SESSION['session_ini'])) {//Stuff}` sea `if (is_null($_SESSION['session_ini'])) {//Stuff}`.

Comment: Si correcto tienes razon, se lo quite pero el login ahora solo me vuelve a redirigir al login (ya verifique que lso datos estan correctos. Al cargar la pagina de login me aparece este mensaje Notice: Undefined index: session_ini in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dashboard\index.php on line 9

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que estás trabajando con una variable booleana (solo almacena `true` o `false)`. En este caso el if pruébalo con

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION['session_ini'])) { 
          //bloque de código
     }
```

otro caso particular también podría ser que compares directamente su valor

```
if ($_SESSION['session_ini']) == true) { 
          //bloque de código
     }
```

Intenta y me indicas a ver que tal te va

Comment: intente ambos casos que me dices, pero me aparece lo mismo. Noto que el error puede ser porque me aparece este mensaje Notice: Undefined index: session_ini in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dashboard\index.php on line 9, que en la linea 9 esta el primer if pero no se como hacer para definirla la primera vez si la defino es luego de enviar el formulario de autenticacion

Comment: Seteala al inicio de tu página a `$_SESSION['session_ini'] = false`

Comment: Si la seteo en false nunca pasara de la pagina de login

Comment: Tienes razón, mi error. Intenta encapsularlas en un array y junto al header las pasas a la otra página ejemplo:

`if ($_REQUEST['correo'] == $log->correo && $pass == $log->contrasena) {
$sesion = array(
                $_SESSION['session_ini'] => true;
                $_SESSION['nombres'] => $log->nombres;
                $_SESSION['apellidos'] => $log->apellidos;
                $_SESSION['correo'] => $log->correo;
                header('Location: index.php?c=Administrador',$sesion);
            } else {
                header('Location: index.php?c=Login');
            }`

Comment: No no funciona, hay alguna otra forma de ver si la sesion se inicio o algo asi?

Comment: `session_status()` te indica si la sesión se ha seteado correctamente o no

Comment: Indagando un poco más acerca de tu caso puedes probar a utilizar el método `empty()` y verificar si te funciona

en este blog me guié para el tema de sesiones en alguna ocasión
http://blog.amarello.com.mx/2007/02/13/una-forma-segura-de-manejar-las-sesiones-en-php/